# How can I parse *.vector.pbf about Mapbox vector tile map?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox, osm.pbf

1. [*.pbf("Protocolbuffer Binary Format") is primarily intended as an alternative to the XML format.](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format)
2. There are two formats of `*.osm.pbf` and `*.vector.pbf`. What tools can I use to open these files? (I know [JOSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF/Software_Compliance) can open *.osm.pbf files, but it can't open *.vector.pbf files.)
3. If I want to write own *.vector.pbf files in Mapbox, how do I work for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The Vector tiles used by Mapbox are serialized as Protocol Buffers.
Protocol Buffers allow you to efficiently compress the vector data inside the tile.

The [Mapbox Tile Specification](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec) is available on github. 
Esri [has also adopted](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/vector-tile-adoption/) the same specification for their products.

You can find a list of parsers, renderers & CLI utilities here: https://github.com/mapbox/awesome-vector-tiles

In the common scenario, you can use [mapbox-gl-js](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js) to render the vector tiles on the client. To generate vector tiles, you can use [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/). This will require uploading your data online in the Studio. You can also use [Mapbox Studio Classic](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio-classic/#darwin) (the older version) to generate the tiles locally.

Internally, Mapbox Studio uses the [tilelive API](https://github.com/mapbox/tilelive), so you can programatically generate the tiles. In the [list above](https://github.com/mapbox/awesome-vector-tiles) there are other good  alternatives as well.

Answer (score 7):

#### Regarding question #2, extracting PBF data

Using GDAL's ogr2ogr is the easiest method (I found).
Given a file named `1583.vector.pbf` decode it to a, for example, shapefile (folder) named `output`:

```
# cmd   show prog.  output format     output name     input name
ogr2ogr -progress -f "ESRI Shapefile" output          1583.vector.pbf
```

#### Regarding question #3, creating PBF data

Use the same command as above but swap the input/outputs and output format:

```
# example source: https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mvt.html
ogr2ogr -f MVT mytileset source.gpkg -dsco MAXZOOM=10
```